# Why does my Spring Boot App hang when started in a Docker Swarm

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm

I created a docker image of a Spring Boot app and when I run it using

```
docker run -d -p 4000:8080 stanlick/stats:v1
```

It works great!  However, when I try to run it as a swarm (even with `replicas:1`) it hangs on startup.

Running

```
docker service logs play-ball_web
```

reveals:

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:12-jdk-alpine 
VOLUME /tmp ARG JAR_FILE 
COPY target/*.jar app.jar 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Hi Stanlick, can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: FROM openjdk:12-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

Comment: Is there any other config files you're using, like YAML, definitions?

Comment: ` version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: stanlick/stats:v1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:`

Comment: Try increasing memory to 100M, maybe it's a memory issue from Max Heap. It's the same error?

Comment: Where would the memory adjustment need to be made?  Dockerfile or docker-compose?  Or is it not enough memory for the Docker engine itself?  I haven't quite connected all the pieces yet!

Comment: _"version: "3" services: web: image: stanlick/stats:v1 deploy: replicas: 1 resources: limits: cpus: "0.1" memory: 50M"_ On memory in your YAML file. Now, everywhere you can set your memory it's recommended, even on ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, friend!  Any clues about why it runs a single container fine without memory flags, however, it won't run a single container using compose file?  This is what is most baffling.

Comment: It's because Docker Swarm must have it's own limit, for not consuming all RAM. Like https://runnable.com/blog/why-is-docker-swarm-consuming-all-available-ram. Changing RAM solved your problem?